# Защитить удаленную ветку GIT от вливания

Tags: git

Можно как то ограничить вливание изменений в определенную ветку размещенную в удаленном репозитории.

К примеру есть репозиторий bare в который вносят изменения разработчики, в нем есть ветка master в которую вливаются только принятые изменения, как ограничить права доступа к ветке master в этом репозитории?

Возможно есть какие то другие способы позволяющие защитить репозиторий от нежелательных вливаний ?

Comment: Ну как, что получилось?

Comment: Nick Volynkin, пока не применил Ваши рекомендации, в ближайшее время займусь этим вопросом, обязательно отпишусь о результатах.

Comment: Ок, буду ждать )

Answer (score 2):

Это называется «защита ветки», по-английски "branch protection". Многие популярные гит-хостинги позволяют защищать ветки.

Например, вот что предлагает GitHub в настройках каждого репозитория:

- (Базовое) Запретить переписывание истории (`git push -f`) или удаление ветки.

  Обязательно включайте это для всех стабильных веток.
- Менять ветку только через пулл-реквест.
  В ветку нельзя будет запушить коммиты напрямую.
  Можно только создать новую фичеветку, создать коммиты в ней и предложить эту ветку в пулл-реквест.

  Это очень разумно и удобно, если в вашей команде принято работать с фичеветками.
- Мержить пулл-реквест только когда все тесты успешно прошли.

  Если вы доверяете своим тестам, стоит включить.
- Распространить эти ограничения на админов (владельцев репозитория).

  Правила должны действовать для всех.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]